# Notepad++ multiline regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got hundreds of files of the type linked here:
http://pastebin.com/fGgLfZf8

But I want to remove all the comments that occupies more than one line
eg.

```
<!--- MPU --->
```

should be left untouched, while

```
<!--
************
blablabla
************
-->
```

should be removed.

I know the Notepad++ feature to lookup through more than a document with regexp and I'm tryin to use it but I have some difficulty.
For a start I'm trying this regexp:

```
<\!\-\-(.*?)\-\->
```

which tested in here: http://www.regextester.com/ works at least partially (because it highlights the comments made of just on line)
But if I copy and paste this regexp on Notepad++ it will match just the one-line comments =\

Does anybody know how to do this in Notepad++?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Next to the "Regular expression" selection in "Search Mode" there is a "matches newline" checkbox (according to @glatapoui it should be noted that this only works in Notepad++ v6, not in previous versions).

[image]

Comment: Wow, writing `<\!\-\-(.*?)\-\->` and selecting that one really seems to work! Thank you. Now I just have to find out how to exclude the mono-line ones

Answer (score 4):

This expression `<!--.+?(?<=[\*\r\n])-->` matched the multi-line comments only in Notepad++ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to catch multi-line text is use the expression:

```
<!---([\S\s]+?)--->
```

\S+ matches all no-space symbols,
\s+ matches all space symbols (including \r \n \t).

It works for notepad++, maybe, otherwise too...

**EDIT:**
At the first look I didn’t noticed that problem issue is catch and delete only multiline comments excluding monoline ones.
I found method of two iterations.
First we need to find and replace by nothing following text

```
<!—-(?:(?!.*—->)[\s\S]+?—->|)
```

That will catch all multiline comments and prefixes of monoline ones.
Then what we need is bring back the monoline prefixes, that we lost:

```
Find:
(.+—->)

Replace:
<!—-\1
```

It will fix monoline comments. Combination of “—->“ can not appear xml code otherwise end of comment.

Comment: This will also match lines without linebreaks.

Comment: @Toto, I didn’t noticed it at the first time. Now I propose another method of two replaces.

Answer (score 0):

`<!--[*a-zA-Z\r\n]*-->`

this one seems to only take multi-line comments in notepad++

Edit: 
little mistake : spaces are a problem with this one.
You can try 
`<!--[\r\n]{1}[* a-zA-Z\r\n]*-->`

Comment: neither of them works for me =\ Do they work in your Notepad++?

Comment: Yes, they work with me. In notepad++ and in Regextester as well.
Could you have some spaces before the first newline of a comment ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple *trick* if it was a single document, is to convert the line endings to Unix .

Menu: `[Edit] -> [EOL Conversion] -> [Unix]`

Then just use simple **\n** to detect newline in your expression.

This way you don't have to change expressions constructed/copied from some online regex builders.

**note**: don't forget to switch line endings back to Windows, just in case.

Comment: How is this answering the question?

Comment: I know the question is about "multiple" documents at once, where my hint won't help this specific case. But I though it could help others who land on this question because they need to find how to handle multi-line search in the NP++ without the need to change a per-constructed search expression that depends on \n for new lines or setting the '.' to be include newlines in search dialog.