# Notepad++ regular expression to find and replace any html tags that contain a certain key word

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I am trying to find a regular expression in Notepad to find and delete all links that contain a special key word like  `<a ... key-word > ... </a>`.
The Links go over multiple lines so it looks more like

```
<a ...
... 
... key-word ...
...
...>
...  
...  
</a>
```

so I tried `<a .+ key-word .+ </a>` and checked ". finds \r and \n" but it cant find anything.
I found similar problems but when I tried to customize them for my need they failed, too.

Comment: If your situation is exactly like as in your example, I would have expected it to fail on extra spaces (there is no space before `</a>` in the text, but there is in your regexp).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ multiline regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934430/notepad-multiline-regex)

Comment: well there are tabs in front of it, are they included in `.` when i check ". finds \r and \n" or by default

Comment: @PascalTänzer Try following `\<a[^>]*key-word[^\<]*\<\/a\>` [Example on regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/jI7yZ7/1)

Comment: Well, the best is to use some XPath. But you can use `<a\s[^<]*key-word[^<]*>[^<]*</a>` regex, too, if the tags are (X)HTML-compliant. With regex, there are always those "if"s :)

Comment: @tchelidze it marks everything even if my keyword is not included

Comment: @PascalTänzer ok, can you show me example on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jI7yZ7/1) ? and i will try to fix

Comment: [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: @tchelidze i got a paste-bin of the original document. Basicly i wanted to rip a list of Items off of a website. Threby i want to keep all `filter-tier-legendary` items. I wanted to approach this issue by deleting all else e.g. `filter-tier-basic`. http://pastebin.com/8xxSsetH