# Finding lines contain no numbers and moving it to the previous line using notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am looking for a way in Notepad++ to find lines not containing any number and moving it to the previous line after adding a separator like "#"

```
moon  215466 
sun & stars world

the sea 345454 
sky @ 464654
cars 135456
school teachers
```

the result i want:

```
moon  215466#sun & stars world

the sea 345454 
sky @ 464654
cars 135456#school teachers
```

I am new to regex so i searched all questions and tried ^[^\d]*$ and ^\D*$ and /^[^0-9]*$/ it find the lines with no numbers but i can't move it to the previous line.

Thank you

Comment: it's a file contains more than 10000 lines so this is a samples of what i want to do not the exact words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

[image]

If you write your text out, it will look something like this:

[image]

What you essentially want to do is to remove the CR (carriage return) and LF (line feed) characters if they are followed by a line containing no digits. The regex for a line containing no digits is `^(\D*)$` - please do ask if you need help understanding how it works. We then replace the CR + LF + Regex match with `#\1` - `#` symbol and `\1` references the contents of the first capturing group, which means the first set of parentheses in your search regex (line with no digits).

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: it works perfectly thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this expression,

```
(?m)(.*?@\s*\d+)\s*(.*?&.*)
```

with a replacement of

```
$1#$2
```

might work, not sure though.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/0LPO4o/1/)

#### Reference

[Notepad++ multiline regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934430/notepad-multiline-regex)

Comment: not working it says: can't find the text (\w+\s*@\s*\d+)\s*[\r\n]*(\w+\s*&\s*\w+.*)

Comment: i updated the samples .i tried your new expression it says: no occurrence was found

Comment: np thanks @Emma for your time

Comment: I think you used "@" as a parameter but actually only some of lines that contain "@" the common thing in the line is containing numbers or not