# RegEx - Finding Text Between Quotes and Replacing Between Parentheses

Tags: regex, replace, find, quotes, parentheses

Okay, I am working on a profile which contains many IDs for objects in general.

All the initial code had to be edited so more functions could be added,  and it's about 1200 ID's I would have to manually edit one by one. So I thought maybe Notepad++ could use RegEx functions to do the whole editing for me.

The problem however, is that I need to **retrieve** the ID from **line 2** which is whitin quotes and then put this ID in **line 1** which has to be between parentheses. This step will be repeated multiple times so instead of being line 2 and line 1, the next set will be line 4 and 3 and so on.

Example:

```
Line 1: < InbagCount(11111) />
Line 2: < ItemID="12345" />
Line 3: < InbagCount(11111) />
Line 4: < ItemID="543" />
```

Now, I need to replace all the **11111** with the next line's ItemID.

this is the code I've been using which matches the text inside ItemID=""

```
(?<=ItemID=")(?:\\.|[^"\\])*(?=")
```

It works to find them but when I click the Replace button this is what happens:

```
InbagCount(?<=ItemID="?:\.|[^"\]*?=")
```

Maybe Notepad++ is not the tool for this job.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can use?

Thanks in advance, I would be very appreciated if you can help me :)

Comment: How did you come to that regex? It tries to match a backslash `\ ` and a dot `.`. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Uhm, well, I found it somewhere in stackoverflow and it worked initially for finding the IDs between the quotes. But it did nothing when trying to replace.

Comment: See my answer, it can work using Notepad++ with regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test with Notepad++ because I don't Windows around, but if I understand your request correctly, it's a simple regex. The key is matching across line boundaries.  You match two lines at once, use a capture group for the text in question and the reconstruct the two lines.

So, for example, you can match with:

```
.*?ItemID="(\d+)" />
```

and replace with:

```
< InbagCount($1) />\n< ItemID="$1" />\n
```

as shown in this [website](http://regexr.com?35qqk). You may be able to actually convert your code using that website.

Comment: You sir are my hero, kinda. That website you linked allowed me to do what I couldn't do in Notepad++. For some reason, when I entered exactly the same search it would not accept the \n even though I had regular expression ticked. Anyway, thank you a ton.

Answer (score 0):

you can use notepad++ macro instead of regex. place your crusor on your second line, press home then click menu macro > start recording, then do the following steps :

1. ctrl+right_arrow(until your number, three time maybe)
2. ctrl+shift+right_arrow
3. ctrl+c(copy)
4. up_arrow
5. home
6. ctrl+right_arrow(until your number, three time maybe)
7. ctrl+shift+right_arrow
8. ctrl+v(paste)

then `stop recording`, and pres `run macro multiple times > until the end of file > run`

Comment: Haha, although that's a clever suggestion, it will not work. The reason is the ItemID will sometimes be 3 characters long and sometimes 4 or 5 characters long. Thanks for the try though!

Comment: thats why i use ctrl, this ignore the length

Comment: Lol, that's amazing, I did not know the Ctrl trick. I guess it could also be done this way but another gentleman also posted a solution with RegEx which resulted in "less" work. Thank you too though, this should work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

**This will work in Notepad++ on Windows**  as you so desired

Assuming this is the text:

```
< InbagCount(11111) />
< ItemID="12345" />
< InbagCount(11111) />
< ItemID="54321" />
```

Ctrl+H:

In "Find what :" `\(([0-9]*).*\r\n.*"([0-9]*)"`

In "Replace with :" `\(\2\) />\n< ItemID="\2"`

The newline issue is explained here: [Notepad++ newline in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398613/notepad-newline-in-regex)

There are actually two regex captures, `\1` for the 11111 tag, and `\2` for the ItemID number.  The one for the 11111 tag wasn't necessary.

This is a bit more involved, but it presumes some strictness (that the capture expression works on line 2), that

- A newline separates the ItemID and the InbagCount line.
- The replacement is contained within parentheses on the previous line
- ItemID is surrounded by double quotes